# compatible assembler tutorials

Tags: assembly, windows-7, 64-bit

I want play with assembler. But I got a 64bit machine.

All tutorials I found are not compatibel with my environment.
I used Win7, 64bit, Visual Studio-> MASM ASsembler.

I started some tutorials but then I got errors like error A2006:undefined symbol : DGROUP  or my created program does not start because it is not compatible with win7

I asked some people and the recommended me to use a old 16bit linker etc.
Is not able to LEARN und practise assembler with 64bit?

Where can I found stuff for that? 
My goal: Able to reprogramm c++ basics in Assembler (loops, conditions etc.)

Answer (score 0):

On 64-bit machine You can run 32-bit code and 64-bit code. You cannot run 16-bit code (without emulator like DosBox). I recommend You masm32.com website for start :)